# Unexpected behaviour with EXCEL Chart MouseMove

Tags: excel, vba

I have some unexpected behaviour with EXCEL VBA an `MouseDown` event.  I want to click on a series and either zoom it (if `LEFT-SHIFT-ALT` is pressed) or pan it (`LEFT-CTRL-SHIFT`).  The code snippet is

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
   
    With ActiveChart
        .GetChartElement x, y, ElementId, Arg1, Arg2    ' What did we click on ...?
        If ElementId = xlSeries Then                    ' ... a data series
            If Button = vbKeyLButton Then
                If Shift = 3 Then       ' SHIFT-CTRL so PAN

                    ' do PAN stuff

                ElseIf Shift = 5 Then  ' SHIFT-ALT so ZOOM

                    ' do ZOOM stuff

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The `LEFT-CTRL-SHIFT` works but `LEFT-ALT-SHIFT` doesn't and EXCEL seems to want to do something else like PAN the entire chart.  I added the `GetChartElement` statement to try to avoid this but it did not solve the issue.  Would appreciate any thoughts - thanks!

Comment: I've had mixed results with these chart-related mouse events. Could you use just left+shift without the alt, or is that reserves for something else? I assume you are using the mousedown event to start the process, then use the mous_move to continue (to increment the pan or zoom). If the mousedown recognizes the shift parameters, then save them as a module variable and reference that instead of the shift argument of mousemove.

Answer (score 0):

After more playing around `LEFT-CTRL-ALT` works so have implemented that.  Still curious to know why `LEFT-SHIFT-ALT` doesn't ...